# Second Router for Back Up

Tags: router

I would like to have a second Wi-Fi router to act as an automatic backup for my current router in the event that my current router fails while I am away. I do not want to risk losing the ability to access my security cameras if one router fails. I am using a TP-Link Archer A6 and would like to use the same model as a second router. Thanks.

Comment: If you are not there to change routers, you need an automatic failover router.

Comment: The chance of a good router failing is very small. You may be better in getting a good router. I can recommend Mikrotik routers. they are enterprise grade routers that are not expensive. Not recommended if you are not into IT yourself though. They are not as easy to manage as a consumer grade router, but they'll never fail.

Comment: Does your ISP even support that? It seems to me you can at best have redundant AP (or maybe, mesh WiFi whatsoever?)

Comment: John. If someone could be there to change routers, what would they need to do to get it connected assuming they had literally no tech. knowledge and no computer access?

Comment: This may depend on your ISP as to whether it's even possible. In the UK, for instance, the router is coded to the ISP. You can't change it yourself without ringing them for a new authorisation & you can't use 3rd party routers.

Comment: If someone can be there, you would need to train them in the basic routine of changeover

Comment: An idea: If you don't get a satisfying answer, perhaps a different question will serve you better.  Maybe ask about load balancing between different hardware.  (The idea being that if one goes down, the load would go to the other.)